# Как сделать генератор вывода запроса?

Tags: python, sql, словари, обработка-данных

```
cur.execute('SELECT admin, status FROM admins')
with cur.fetchall() as admin, status:
    ...
```

Мне нужен словарь `{admin:status}`, но боюсь что у меня все результаты собьются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cur.execute('SELECT admin, status FROM admins')
for admin, status in cur.fetchall():
    ...
```